# Many forms on website calls same file to process them PHP

Tags: php, forms, include, global-variables

I am working on a website with multiple forms. All of those forms are in a single php file. I just include the file to use the default form. Once the default form is submitted it goes to the next one in the file. The things is I need to pass the data of some of the forms to the ones after it. My question is can I set the value of the fields to a global variable so I don't have to pass it along in a hidden field or use session variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you have an option... Sessions would be the best way to go, and it doesnt have to be cumbersome you can save the entire $_POST array by doing something like:

```
$_SESSION['previousPost'] = $_POST;
```

Comment: Your answer seems to have the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**NO** this is not possible... you will have to use hidden OR Session.

All PHP page variables are expired when the page is sent over to the client, you need to save data on server or client, if you need it on preceding pages

Answer (score 1):

Can you give an example of the data you're trying to pass along? It ultimately depends on how long you want the data to persist. If the user lets the session expire, you're going to loose that data and should probably have stored it in a hidden field. Otherwise, session *should* be alright.

`$_SESSION['key'] = 'val';`

Answer (score 1):

First, your set up with multiple forms in once php is going to be a maintenance nightmare in the future. But that's not your question... if you're going this route, you you can POST to the same script that contains the forms. With each successive submission, you add to the global $_POST variable.

The trick is to make sure you continue to pass along the previous form's data with every following submission. This means you'd likely have to maintain hidden fields for the previous form's data--it's not elegant, and prone to problems, e.g. it's a linear workflow (one-way).

You'd be better off maintaining the data in a session, or a serialized object (with appropriate accessors) in the session. If you have a database, you can always build a single record in steps, populating a record's columns with each forms submission.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Set it in the session
You can set it in the session like this:

```
$_SESSION[key]=value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better practice for you to look in to using MySQL or another database to store those values, then have them drawn from the database as needed on the subsequent forms. Depending on how the structure of the one large PHP file is, odds are it will take a page refresh to get to the next form, in which case, if you don't need the data persistence of a MySQL database, I would highly suggest creating a Session, storing the data from the first form in a session, bringing that session to the next form, and using the data from the session variable to access the values you need.